# Applying a subset to repeated measures using a unique ID and conditions?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, filtering

I am trying to find a way to subset or filter my dataset (repeated measures of individuals) using a conditional statement on the first measure.  In other words, I want to filter the dataset to only include data for all time points for the individuals which have a specific condition present at time point 1.

Example Data:

```
Puck_Number <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Date <- as.Date(c('2020-07-29','2020-07-29','2020-07-29','2020-07-29','2020-07-29','2020-07-29','2020-09-07','2020-09-07','2020-09-07','2020-09-07','2020-09-07','2020-09-07','2020-09-22','2020-09-22','2020-09-22','2020-09-22','2020-09-22','2020-09-22'))
Bleached <- c(1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1)
Alive <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
Data <- data.frame(Puck_Number, Date, Bleached, Alive)
```

Which will produce the following:

```
       Puck_Number       Date Bleached Alive
1            1 2020-07-29        1     1
2            2 2020-07-29        0     1
3            3 2020-07-29        1     1
4            4 2020-07-29        1     1
5            5 2020-07-29        0     1
6            6 2020-07-29        1     1
7            1 2020-09-07        1     1
8            2 2020-09-07        0     1
9            3 2020-09-07        1     1
10           4 2020-09-07        1     1
11           5 2020-09-07        0     0
12           6 2020-09-07        1     1
13           1 2020-09-22        0     0
14           2 2020-09-22        0     1
15           3 2020-09-22        0     0
16           4 2020-09-22        1     1
17           5 2020-09-22        0     0
18           6 2020-09-22        1     1
```

What I want to include through filtering or subsetting is only those which have a 1 in the bleached column during the Date of '2020-07-29' and the repeated measure of those individuals for the entire dataset.

So I am looking for the data to look like this:

```
      Puck_Number       Date Bleached Alive
1            1 2020-07-29        1     1
3            3 2020-07-29        1     1
4            4 2020-07-29        1     1
6            6 2020-07-29        1     1
7            1 2020-09-07        1     1
9            3 2020-09-07        1     1
10           4 2020-09-07        1     1
12           6 2020-09-07        1     1
13           1 2020-09-22        0     0
15           3 2020-09-22        0     0
16           4 2020-09-22        1     1
18           6 2020-09-22        1     1
```

The puck number is a unique identifier for each individual (repeated for each measurement) and I suspect that it may help in this filtering, but I haven't come across a way to accomplish this with the R skill set I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
with(Data, Data[Puck_Number %in% Puck_Number[Date == as.Date("2020-07-29") & Bleached], ])
```

Output

```
   Puck_Number       Date Bleached Alive
1            1 2020-07-29        1     1
3            3 2020-07-29        1     1
4            4 2020-07-29        1     1
6            6 2020-07-29        1     1
7            1 2020-09-07        1     1
9            3 2020-09-07        1     1
10           4 2020-09-07        1     1
12           6 2020-09-07        1     1
13           1 2020-09-22        0     0
15           3 2020-09-22        0     0
16           4 2020-09-22        1     1
18           6 2020-09-22        1     1
```

Comment: This worked perfect.  I hadn't used `with` before, thank you for showing me something new.

Answer (score 0):

Or a tidyverse way

```
library(tidyverse)
subset <- Data %>% filter(Date == as.Date("2020-07-29", format = "%Y-%m-%d") & Bleached == 1) %>%
  select(Puck_Number) %>% left_join(Data)

> subset
   Puck_Number       Date Bleached Alive
1            1 2020-07-29        1     1
2            3 2020-07-29        1     1
3            4 2020-07-29        1     1
4            6 2020-07-29        1     1
5            1 2020-09-07        1     1
6            3 2020-09-07        1     1
7            4 2020-09-07        1     1
8            6 2020-09-07        1     1
9            1 2020-09-22        0     0
10           3 2020-09-22        0     0
11           4 2020-09-22        1     1
12           6 2020-09-22        1     1
```